# Execute PHP function inside the admin area

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, dashboard

I want to ask if there is a hook for executing php inside the admin area, my problem is I'm trying to do the get_posts wordpress function inside a popup frame using the thickbox jQuery plugin, using an anchor, and I linked this anchor to a page contains my code

I do the main function in the functions.php file which is

```
function fetch_all_companies() {
$companies_args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'company',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$companies = get_posts($companies_args);
return $companies;}
```

when executing this function inside the admin panel I got this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_all_companies()
```

any ideas ???

Answer (score 1):

Hook into the `admin_init` action...

```
add_action('admin_init', 'fetch_all_companies');

function fetch_all_companies() {
    //do something here...
}
```

#### note:

What file are you running your `fetch_all_companies()` function from and where is it located (the path to the file)? Its likely the WordPress environment is not loaded on the destination file which is why your function appears to be undefined.

Comment: Not working, The same error